# Sass negative variable value?

Tags: css, sass, compass-sass

I have a couple of scss selectors where I use the same amount positive and negative, as in:

```
padding: 0 15px 15px;
margin: 0 -15px 20px -15px;
```

I'd prefer to use a variable for all the 15px amounts, but this does not work:

```
$pad: 15px;
padding: 0 $pad $pad;
margin: 0 -$pad 20px -$pad;
```

The margin amounts convert to positive numbers.  Am I missing something?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

create a function

```
@function neg($val) {
  @return $val * -1
};
```

then I use it like this

```
$gutter: 30px;

.header {
  margin: $gutter neg($gutter);
}
```

Answer (score 253):

Try it like this

```
margin: 0 (-$pad) 20px (-$pad);
```

Comment: Automatically tried this approach - seems not to be working when using in calc function. Edit: Seems like you don't need to use parentheses when using calc, but you do need to interpolate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17982111/sass-variable-in-css-calc-function

Answer (score 61):

A more sane solution according to sass guidelines would be to `interpolate` variables like the following example:

```
margin: 0 -#{$pad} 20px -#{$pad};
```

An example: https://www.sassmeister.com/gist/c9c0208ada0eb1fdd63ae47830917293

Comment: @Green You can always check the example link: https://www.sassmeister.com/gist/c9c0208ada0eb1fdd63ae47830917293

Comment: This is better than the accepted answer because it works when using a mixin inside it also :)

Answer (score 10):

I'm adding my two-penneth after considering the two previous answers, but then reading this (emphasis mine):

> You should **especially avoid using interpolation like `#{$number}px`**.
>   This doesn’t actually create a number! It creates an unquoted string
>   that looks like a number, but won’t work with any number operations or
>   functions. Try to make your math unit-clean so that `$number` already
>   has the unit `px`, or write **`$number * 1px`**.
>
> [Source](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/values/numbers)

Therefore  I believe the correct way would be as follows, which preserves the mathematical abilities of SASS/SCSS:

```
$pad: 15px;
padding: 0 $pad $pad;
margin: 0 $pad*-1 20px $pad*-1;
```

Comment: At first glance, it seems to be nit-picking (your answer), but on second glance it really is the better answer. After all, if the variable does become a negative variable the answer becomes positive!

    $pad: -2rem;
    ...
    margin: 0 -#{$pad}; // becomes margin: 0 --2rem;
    margin: 0 $pad*-1; // becomes margin: 0 2rem;

Comment: this is a novel solution but I disagree that it's the "correct" way - do you think it's even better than this similar solution?
`margin: 0 0 - $pad 20px 0 - $pad;`

Answer (score 3):

The official sass guides suggest a similar solution to the (currently) highest voted answer - instead of wrapping the minus-sign inside the parens, put it outside, e.g.

```
$pad: 15px;
padding: 0 $pad $pad;
margin: 0 -($pad) 20px -($pad);
```

source: https://sass-lang.com/documentation/operators/numeric#unary-operators

and per [#comment-72915126](https://#comment-72915126) you would want to interpolate the sass value when it appears inside a css `calc` function:

```
margin: calc(#{-$pad} - 10px);
```

strangely, the parens are no longer required - perhaps the string interpolation acts in a similar way to wrapping it in parens?

(I'm using prettier@2.3 and dart-sass@1.49)

Comment: That depends on the use case. If you have `margin: 0 -($pad);` this will produce `margin: -16px;`, but you might want it to produce `margin: 0 -16px;` and then you need to have `margin: 0 (-$pad);` to achieve that.

Answer (score 1):

The answer from @Bouh worked for me but I had to interpolate the variable to handle other variables that have calcs() in them

```
@function neg($val) {
  @return calc(#{$val} * -1)
};
```

For example:

```
$gutter: 30px;
$gutter-half: calc(#{$gutter} / 2);

.header {
  margin: $gutter neg($gutter-half);
}
```