# Negative rems (CSS) being compiled as positive

Tags: html, css, sass, gwt

I have this sample block of code:

```css
#button a:hover{
        outline: 0.0625em solid #fff;
        outline-offset: -0.0625rem;
}
```

But in real life it gets compiled to:

```css
#button a:hover{
    outline: 0.0625em solid #fff;
    outline-offset: 0.0625rem;
}
```

No matter what the value is (i.e. -1rem, -2rem) the negative rem value will always come out positive in real life so it's not a rounding issue. I found someone with the same issue (see link below) on GitHub but they have not posted their resolution.

https://github.com/vaadin/sass-compiler/issues/100

I'm using maven to compile and GWT framework. I looked up the documentation for both among a crap ton of other documentations on rems and haven't found anything. There's not any coded specification in my system that instructs the behavior of rem so it's not a developer error.

This is only happening in rem's. Em's, px's, etc. all work just fine.

Any thoughts would be helpful thanks.

Comment: plain css works, try insert the value via calc( value * -1)  or the same way you would insert a calc() rule. it shouldpreserve the negative signs . `#{}`

Comment: Yep, that makes sense but it doesn't work for some reason. :( forgot to mention I tried this earlier

Comment: okay, you should add your fails to your question, it might ring a bell to someone else ;)

Comment: did you see that question BTW : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13296419/sass-negative-variable-value

Comment: I have, I applied the same principles in CSS and still nothing

Comment: looks like working to me : https://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/JjKBXjZ (view compiled css)

Comment: Has to be something with my compiler or framework then, thank you!